# Cannot modify outbound call TWILIO

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am currently exploring the Twilio Python Api.
I a m trying to modify a call in progress but i managed to do it only with incoming calls.
For example, see this code ( from the Twilio doc)

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls('CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
             .update(twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy there</Say></Response>')

print(call.to)
```

I ran it on a Python flask server and it works only with incoming calls while outbound calls will crash and not execute the new Twiml.

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio Console should show you the error that is occurring. Login to twilio.com, click Monitor, click Logs, expand Errors, click Error logs.

Likely the call is not currently in progress or the call sid is wrong.

The update call function doesn't differentiate between an inbound call or an outbound call.

If the Twilio Console is not displaying the error, then trap the exception on your server and view the exception. I am not familiar with the Python SDK but the SDK I use will always display a message from the Twilio REST API when there is an exception.